# iframe show only after click?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, iframe

I have the following code: Iframe is being shown but I like to hide it until form is submitted. is it better maybe to use Div instead of iframe? I like to get get rid of div thats already there when form is submitted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function showIFrame() {  
 var iframe = document.getElementById("myiframe");  
 iframe.style.display="block";  
}  
</script>
```

in my css file

```
#myiframe {
display:none; }

<form name="search" id="search" method="get"      action="http://tmccaffery.outsideagents.com/travel/car/search.rvlx" target="carsearch">

<iframe id="myframe" name="carsearch" width="535" height="625" scrolling="no"   frameborder="0"></iframe>


<button type="submit" id="SearchCarButton" class="submitBtn" onclick="showIFrame()"/>  <span>Search</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `id="myframe"` in the HTML and `#myiframe` in the CSS.

Either change `id="myframe"` to `id="myiframe"` or change `#myiframe` to `#myframe`.

Comment: I did what you said but the Iframe is still showing, I want to hide iframe until you click on submit.

Comment: You did change just one of those, right, and not both? http://jsfiddle.net/6NZaS/

Answer (score 0):

```
iframe.style.visibility="hidden";
```

and to show it:

```
iframe.style.visibility="visible";
```

Edit: And you can use the  onsubmit="JavaScriptCode" event to trigger the change.

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to this :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function showIFrame() {  
var iframe = document.getElementById("myiframe");  
iframe.style.visibility="visible";
}  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong id - in your css you're using "#myiframe" instead of "#myframe" - no "i".

Here's the correct code:

```
#myframe { display:none; }
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery have load event that is executed when iframe is loaded:

```
$('#myframe').load(function() {
   $(this).show();
});
```